# Angular mat-tab-nav-bar how can I change the color of the text?

Tags: angular, angular-material, navbar

By doing the following I can change the colour of the text of the tab :

```
.mat-tab-link {
  color: black;
}
```

But the text is very slightly transparent witch gives it a grey appearance ( on a white background ) when the tab is not selected. How can I set the transparency / CSS for non selected tabs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the specific classes combination by looking at the DOM and then specify that, or just do:

```
.mat-tab-link {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

You might need to use `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-link {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Don't use ng-deep it's deprecated. Use Scss instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add style inside `styles.css`.

```
.mat-tab-link{
  color:#3182ce;
}
.mat-tab-link.mat-tab-label-active{
  color:#ccc;
}
```

Here is Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-nav-qka9gi?file=styles.css